# Creating a simple D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Well this is a noob question. I am just about beginning to explore the D3jS library.

I am trying to create a simple bar chart right now. For some reasons, the chart is not getting created. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
 <style>.chart div {
    background-color:red;
    border:1px solid blue;
}</style>
 <div id="ReportContent_ReportContent" style="border: 1px solid #58595d; border: 1px solid rgba(88, 89, 93, .3);">

<svg></svg>
  </div>


 <script>
    var data = [{ "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00", "Product": "Deposits", "Actual": 330393232.5, "Forecast": 495589848.75, "Target": 495589848.75 }, { "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00", "Product": "Fee Based", "Actual": 111868709.42, "Forecast": 167803064.13, "Target": 167803064.13 }, { "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00", "Product": "Lending", "Actual": 18146873.33, "Forecast": 27220309.995, "Target": 27220309.995 }];

    var width = 420,
        barHeight = 20;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
        .range([0, width]);

    var chart = d3.select('#ReportContent_ReportContent svg')
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

    var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data, function (d) { return d.Actual; })
      .enter().append("g")
       .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("width", function(d) { return d.Actual; })
        .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
        .attr("fill", "#000000");

    bar.append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.Actual) - 3; })
        .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function (d) { return d.Product; });
</script>
```

Comment: Typo? Try `d3.select('#ReportContent_ReportContent')` (note different capitalisation).

Comment: Thanks for correcting that. But inspite of the correction nothing happens. I checked the source and nothing gets appended :(

Comment: Well your scale is wrong and your data as well (and a few other things). Have a look at [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/) on how to create a bar chart.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff. I made a few changes (I am still learning). The rectangles now get created in the source. But there is nothing except text on the screen :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems is that you're trying to access properties of the objects that belong to the array.

Here:

```
    var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
                .data(data.Actual)
```

try to do this instead:

```
    var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
                   .data(data, function(d) {return d.Actual;})
```

I haven't tested the solution myself, but this should get rid of one of the errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. One of the errors is gone. I am assuming the data is also wrong. Not sure what is wrong though. The following is one of the nodes that got inserted. For some strange reason, the width is set as NaN.

<g transform="translate(0,0)"><rect width="NaN" height="19" fill="#000000"></rect><text x="NaN" y="10" dy=".35em">[object Object]</text></g>

Comment: I have changed the bar.append("text")

I was appending the wrong property.